# for loop for each month of year

Tags: php, date, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop in PHP to add to an HTML `<select>` tag dropdown, that allows people to pick their birth month.

Heres my code which isn't working:

```
<p>
    <label for="signup_birth_month">Birthday:</label>
    <select name="signup_birth_month" id="signup_birth_month">
        <option value="">Select Month</option>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
            $month_name = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2011));
            echo '<option value="'.$month_name.'"'.$month_name.'></option>';
        }?>
    </select>
</p>
```

How do I write a for loop that returns the name of each month in year?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to quote the `value` key with:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $month_name . "\">" . $month_name . "</option>";
```

In addition, I'd probably prefer something like this:

```
$months = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", ..., "Dec");
foreach ($months as $month) {
    echo "<option value=\"" . $month . "\">" . $month . "</option>";
}
```

It seems bizarre that you would make all those unnecessary calls to `date` and `mktime` when you *know* what the values should be.

This array version has the same number of lines and it seems a lot clearer in intent (at least to me).

Answer (score 3):

```
for($iM =1;$iM<=12;$iM++){
echo date("M", strtotime("$iM/12/10"));}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP code to print out the name of each month:

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 
for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){ 
    $month = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10)); 
    echo $month . ","; 
    // It will print: January,February,.............December,
}
?>
```

Comment: Code only answers are low quality and brought up for review, your code isn't wrong so I salvaged it by cleaning it up and adding some text.  If you want to earn reputation on Stackoverflow, there's no getting around learning the English language and writing at least a few sentences over every piece of code, about what it does and how it answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you not seeing the month name get printed in the select box?

I think this should do the trick:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $month_name . "\">" . $month_name . "</option>";
```

Comment: A `printf()` would look nicer, ie `printf('<option value="%1$s">%1$s</option>', $month_name);`

Comment: @Phil didn't know about printf. Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 1):

Very simple!

```
function getLocalMonthName($locale, $monthnum)
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, $locale.".UTF-8");
    return ucfirst(strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthnum, 1)));
}

print getLocalMonthName("pt_BR", 1); // returns Janeiro
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fix the HTML part.

```
echo '<option value="'.$month_name.'">'.$month_name.'</option>';
```

Dont forget to set the default timezone before

```
date_default_timezone_set('Your/Timezone');
```

Or else you will get a E_WARNING for date() and mktime() (if you set error_reporting(E_ALL)).
Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php for valid timezones.

Alternatively, you could also use something like

```
$i = 1;
$month = strtotime('2011-01-01');
while($i <= 12)
{
    $month_name = date('F', $month);
    echo '<option value="'. $month_name. '">'.$month_name.'</option>';
    $month = strtotime('+1 month', $month);
    $i++;
}
```

But the for loop is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution:

```
print '<option value="" disabled selected>Select month</option>';
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 12; $i ++ ) { 
    print '<option value="' . $i . '">' . date( 'F', strtotime( "$i/12/10" ) ) . '</option>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hey if you only needy for months and don't wants to make an array list of months you can try it**

```
<select>

  <?php  for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){  ?>
    <option value="<?= $i ?>"><?= date('M', strtotime('2020-'.$i.'-01')) ?></option>
  <?php }  ?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to loop through months based on the month format.

```
function months($month_format="F"){
    $months =  [];
    for ($i = 1; $i <=12; $i++) {
        $months[] = date($month_format, mktime(0,0,0,$i));
    }
    return $months;
}


var_dump(months());
//returns
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "January"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "February"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "March"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "April"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "May"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "June"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "July"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "August"
  [8]=>
  string(9) "September"
  [9]=>
  string(7) "October"
  [10]=>
  string(8) "November"
  [11]=>
  string(8) "December"
}



var_dump(months("M"))
//returns
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Jan"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Feb"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "Mar"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "Apr"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "May"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "Jun"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "Jul"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "Aug"
  [8]=>
  string(3) "Sep"
  [9]=>
  string(3) "Oct"
  [10]=>
  string(3) "Nov"
  [11]=>
  string(3) "Dec"
}
```

Personally, I use this function the loop into associative arrays and get html select and even target the selected value.

```
function html_selected($selected_option, $html_select_attributes, $options_and_values_array, $has_placeholder=false){
    $c = count($options_and_values_array);
    if ($has_placeholder){
        $c--;
    }
    
    if ($c===0){
        return "";
    }
    
    $select="<select $html_select_attributes>";
    foreach ($options_and_values_array as $k=>$v){
        if ((string)$k===(string)$selected_option){
            $f = "selected";
        }else{
            $f = "";
        }
        if (strpos($k,'"') !==-1){
            $dl = "'";
        }else{
            $dl = '"';
        }
        $select.="<option value=$dl".$k."$dl $f>$v</option>";    
    }
    $select.="</select>";
    
    return $select;
}
```

So all together, You have

```
$months = months();
echo html_selected("April","class='select-month'",array_combine($months,$months));

//returns
<select class='select-month'><option value='January' >January</option><option value='February' >February</option><option value='March' >March</option><option value='April' selected>April</option><option value='May' >May</option><option value='June' >June</option><option value='July' >July</option><option value='August' >August</option><option value='September' >September</option><option value='October' >October</option><option value='November' >November</option><option value='December' >December</option></select>
```